# Configuring local server with node js

Tags: node.js, xampp, localhost, wamp, localserver

I have Node JS installed on my system, how can i configure local server using node js without wamp or xampp so that i can run my applications in my local machine? can somebody help me with the step by step procedure?

Comment: Your get or write a small node.js app that runs a web server (takes about 10 lines of code) and then you start that app.  node.js is NOT a web server itself.  It can run apps that are web servers once you have such an app.  Express is a node.js framework that makes web servers pretty easy.  Here's a simple example web server in Express: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1):

Node JS makes it really simple to create a server. All you need to do is write a file : server.js.

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.end('Hello World!');
});

server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

Open cmd and write

```
node server.js
```

Go to your browser and open

```
localhost:8000
```

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for configure local server without wamp || Xampp

```
var http = require('http'); // 1 - Import Node.js core module

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {   // 2 - creating server

    // handle incoming requests here..

});

server.listen(5000); //3 - listen for any incoming requests

console.log('Node.js web server at port 5000 is running..')
```

Comment: Please format your code by prepending with four spaces, or select the code and click the `{}` button in the edit page.